# Firefox sharing login sessions between private mode windows

Tags: firefox, private-browsing

I noticed that if I login to SE in a private mode window using Firefox v57.0 Quantum (x64 on Windows 7 Pro) and then open a second private mode window and navigate to e.g. [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/), I see the same login session in that second private browsing window.

On another hand, if I open a third, regular (non-private) window, and navigate to SE, I do not have access to the login session but must login separately.

So what is happening is that all private mode windows have access to the same login sessions. I would have thought that each private mode window would encapsulate its own login sessions.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Private mode uses its own session.  It’s just discarded when the last process is closed.  What you describe is expected behavior

Comment: Same thing happening to me too but in my case it is opening an email Id which I have not logged on to in the regular window. Seems like a serious bug to me.

Comment: Related: [Can Firefox be used with multiple Private Browsing sessions?](https://superuser.com/q/653094/511411)